# Trying to Update Records in an Access Table From Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I think my VBA should be something like what you see below, but it isn't working.  I'm getting an error message that reads: "No value given for one or more required parameters."

```
Sub Execute_UpdateQuery()
    Dim NumOfRec As Integer
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRng As Range
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    DBFullName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Stakeholder.accdb"

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & DBFullName & ";"

NumOfRec = 0
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

With Worksheets("Temp")
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Temp")
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

i = 11
    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A11:A" & LastRow)
    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
        For j = 2 To 8
        Debug.Print .Cells(i, j).Value
            TheUpdate = .Cells(10, j).Value
            cn.Execute "UPDATE ALLL_HISTORY SET " & TheUpdate & " = '" & .Cells(i, j).Value & _
                    "' WHERE DESC1 = " & "'" & .Cells(i, 1).Value & "'", , adExecuteNoRecords
            NumOfRec = NumOfRec + 1
        Next j
    i = i + 1
    Next rCell
End With

MsgBox (NumOfRec & " records were updated.")
cn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

These images may help.

[image]

[image]

Any thoughts on what could be wrong?  This should be pretty close!!

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Comment: `DESC1` field appears to be text. Try wrapping the update value in single quote. `WHERE DESC1 = '" & .Cells(i,1).Value  & "'"`. You may need to do in the `SET` syntax as well. Access requires this for text type columns.

Comment: Don't know what column type you have for `LLR_Product` but try this: `cn.Execute "UPDATE ALLL_HISTORY SET " & TheUpdate & " = '" & .Cells(i, j).Value & "' WHERE DESC1 = " & .Cells(i, 1).Value, NumOfRec, adExecuteNoRecords`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass `3-SYN` to SQL, it attempts to parse this as `numeric value 3 minus value of SYN` - which, as `SYN` isn't a column name, is presumed to be a parameter.

The error suggests it can't find that parameter. Wrapping the value you're passing in quotes tells the SQL that it's text and should fix your problem.

```
cn.Execute "UPDATE ALLL_HISTORY SET " & TheUpdate & " = '" & .Cells(i, j).Value & _
        "' WHERE DESC1 = " & .Cells(i, 1).Value, NumOfRec, adExecuteNoRecords
```

Comment: Yeah, that did it.  Thanks everyone!